# Defining trips and stop sequences for bidirectional route in GTFS

Tags: gtfs

I'm trying to define a GTFS feed for a ferry crossing between 2 ports (A <-> B). There may be 2 ferries running between these ports.

routes.txt

```
route_id,route_short_name,route_long_name,route_desc,route_type
AB,A-B,A << >> B,Ferry travelling between A and B,4
```

calender.txt

```
service_id,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday,start_date,end_date
FULLWEEK,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,20180103,20180430
```

trips.txt

```
route_id,service_id,trip_id,trip_headsign,direction_id,shape_id,wheelchair_accessible,bikes_allowed
AB,FULLWEEK,a_b,B Dest,0,ab_shape,1,1
AB,FULLWEEK,b_a,B Dest,1,ab_shape,1,1
```

stops.txt

```
stop_id,stop_name,stop_desc,stop_lat,stop_lon,location_type
A,B-A,Travelling from B to A,xxxx,xxxx,1
B,A-B,Travelling from A to B,xxxx,xxxx,1
```

stop_times.txt

```
trip_id,arrival_time,departure_time,stop_id,stop_sequence
a_b,02:45:00,03:00:00,A,1
a_b,04:45:00,05:00:00,A,1
b_a,00:45:00,01:00:00,B,2
b_a,03:45:00,04:00:00,B,2
```

^^ this is where the errors appear in the feed validator

> Duplicate stop_sequence in trip_id a_b

I can't work if I should be using 2 routes instead of 1 (and stop using the `direction_id` value in `trips.txt`) and what the sequence of the timetables are, since the timetables at both ports may not match up as a sequence as there may be multiple ferries running between the 2 ports.

Thank you.

Comment: I've realised that stop_sequence for each port could just auto increment, it doesn't have to have a relationship to the other port?

Comment: Or should I be adding a new trip in trips.txt for every scheduled journey that day? I.e there could be 50 duplicated trips with all the same info except the trip_id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out, basically `trips.txt` must contain an entry for every scheduled departure. I was treating trips like routes, when in fact every departure is it's own "trip".